# Python Requests Randomize User-Agent header "every" request loop without restart

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests

from user_agent import generate_user_agent

url = "https://myweb.com/myapi/test"

headers = {f'User-Agent': generate_user_agent()}

while True:

   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

   print(response.text)
```

i want no restart , loop random ua for every request new ua string

They test this code giving 1 one same ua and looping work but i need change ua for "every" request

new useragent = need reboot restart code but i dont want restart code, directly loop, (loop working but same ua) i want get random ua for every every req
reget without restart sry for my eng

Comment: Did you create a new user account just to ask the same question you did earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77857841/51685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only computing `headers` once outside the loop, so of course the user agent won't change. Move it inside the loop.

```
import requests

from user_agent import generate_user_agent

url = "https://myweb.com/myapi/test"


while True:
    headers = {"User-Agent": generate_user_agent()}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.text)
```